# Why is *"Where did you move from Paris to?" ungrammatical?

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, wh-words

If I'm not mistaken *"Where did you move from Paris to?", while "Where did you move to from Paris?" as well as both "You moved from Paris to London" and "You moved to London from Paris"(at least with the proper context and intonation) seem okay. How does this contrast arise? (I'm mostly interested in an explanation in term of Chomskian generative grammar)

Comment: "Where did you move from Paris to" sounds OK to me.

Comment: Ok, as I am not a native speaker, my question might be vacuous then...

Comment: Although, it's been hard for me to find examples of similar sentences on the Internet, so it might not be the kind of sentence that a speaker would be likely to produce ... I'm not sure whether you can trust my judgement.

Comment: Try a discourse "I moved from Nice to Paris, and then from Paris to (inaudible Tralfamadore)". "*Where* did you from Paris to?".

Comment: I find "Where did you move from Paris to?" completely grammatical and normal (British English native speaker).

Comment: It looks OK. The prenuclear "where" is complement of the prep "to": "Where did you move from Paris to __?"

Comment: These are all OK for me, but what's odd is _?Where did you move from to Paris?_. It seems to me that _moving to_ is askable with _where_, but _moving from_ is not. One reason is that the versions that keep _move to_ together are significantly more idiomatic and natural than the versions that treat _to_ as a separable preposition instead of part of a predicate.

Comment: Perfectly cromulent sentence in my view.

Comment: This sentence would probably work as a constituency test, and I think it shows (being grammatical) that "move to" is not a constituent.

Comment: Have you considered that this question might be more appropriate for the English Language Learners site since it’s about you learning the nuances of grammar in English rather than understanding grammar as a general field of study?

Answer (score 1):

The example is okay if you get the stress right. There is some tendency to put the main sentence stress on "Paris", taking the focus to be "Paris", but that gives a bad result:

> *Where did you move from **Paris** to?

Actually, the focus is the object of "to" or the prepositional phrase "to where", and in that case, the main stress has to on the logical object of "to" or on what is left of the prepositional phrase after the question word has been fronted:

> **Where** did you move from Paris to?
>      Where did you move from Paris **to**?

Comment: I'd say it's even OK with stress on *Paris* in a context where you know someone moved between a series of cities: "From London I moved to Paris..." "And where did you move from **Paris** to?"

Comment: @TKR, Good point.